# Computer power off directly

Tags: shutdown, desktop-computer

Computer specifications:

- case: Tecware Alpha White Mid Tower
- mobo: MSI 970 Gaming AM3+ Chipset
- CPU: AMD FX 6300 Hexa Cores
- RAM: 2x 4GB G.Skills DDR3
- GPU: Palit GTX 1060 Dual Fan 3GB 192bit DDR5
- storage: 1TB WDC and 120GB Samsung SSD 750 EVO
- CPU Cooling: Deepcool Maelstrom AIO Liquid Cooling
- PSU: Corsair 450W
  Mon: HP 22" LED

For more specific information about my motherboard, processor, RAM and graphics card, please see this [link](https://postimg.org/image/hrg9mpopv/)

The computer is almost 2 years old, and the graphics card is 6 months old. My issue that started 2 days ago is that when I turn my computer on, it boots up normally to Windows 10. Then after 10-15 mins., it will power off. No error from Windows, no warning, even the "Your PC is Shutting Down" message from Windows is not appearing. It's just directly powering off.

I tried:

1. Replaced PSU with Rave 450w
2. Removed graphics card
3. Removed RAM 1 by 1
4. Removed everything, cleaned it, reapplied thermal paste on CPU, then reassembled.

Note: Latest temperatures as per BIOS is: CPU: from 40° to 85° (within 5 mins.), motherboard: 35°

After everything, the problem still occurs.

Comment: The powering off appears to be the CPU overheating. Are you sure the fan is working and the pump is moving fluid, and that the heatsink is making good contact with the CPU? Maybe a heatsink mount or something broke. The thermal paste should be smashed down to a super thin layer if the heatsink is making good contact. You need to find out why the CPU is overheating.

Comment: @Appleoddity Hi, yes all fans are working and checked. Also, heat sink is mounted correctly. About the fluid I'm not sure about this since the tube is really short. [see here](https://postimg.org/image/l9exx92eb/). I suspect that the issue here is the liquid cpu cooler is not functioning properly, or my CPU is faulty. Today I'll try to change the liquid cooler to a fan, see if the temp improves.

Comment: Good idea. Why does it look like a nut is missing on the one post?

Comment: @Appleoddity I was in the middle of replacing it with a fan :). New update, after replacing the liquid cooler with a fan, temperature is now stable and improving. Fluctuating from 30 - 41 degrees. Going to observe this for the whole day while playing several games.

Comment: Motherboard diagnostic check perhaps?